# Wordpress Add user by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have a wordpress website en would like to create users with a button (to start with)

It works in pieces, but i can't get this two pieces to work together

i have this piece of code (works on functions.php , but not in my createaccount.php file)

```
 $userid = new WP_User(wp_create_user( 'My_new_name' , '123458' , 'me@mail.com'));
   $userid->set_role('client');  //custom role 'client' already set
```

this on jquery //php file works when echo 'test';

```
$(document).ready( function() {

   $('#newbtnaccount').click( function() {

      $.post('php/createaccount.php', { } , 
                      function(data) {

                         alert(data);

    });

  });
});
```

i already tried a lot of options but nothings seems to work yet.

Anyone who can Help?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the error message in your question when you run the `createaccount.php`?

Comment: when i add the php i get this message:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

when i only echo something it works

when i add this php to functions.php this code works, but i would like to trigger this function and add attribute later

Comment: So did you look at the error log on your server to see what is happening?

Comment: Have you loaded WordPress in `createaccount.php`? WordPress functions won't be available to you unless you explicitly load WordPress in a custom file like this.

Comment: i tried using
global $wpdb; 
AND
 include("../../../wp-load.php");

Comment: i watched on my server logs and found out this error line: PHP Fatal error: Class 'WP_User' not found in ... and PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../../wp-load.php' for inclusion

i rechecked the path and it worked with include('../wp-load.php'); instead of ../../../

Answer (score 2):

In wordpress you can make an AJAX request to *admin-ajax.php* and attach functions in your *functions.php* file with `wp_ajax_my_action` (for logged users) and `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action` (for non logged users).

#### 1. Set the admin-ajax.php url available as JS variable

In *header.php* add this in the head part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>
```

#### 2. Request the function through ajax

You need to add an `action` parameter to your request reflecting the function that you need to call in *functions.php* - let's call it `create_user`.

```
$.post(ajax_url, {action: 'create_user'} , function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

#### 3. Create the function in functions.php

Inside *functions.php*, add the following:

```
function ajax_create_user() {
  $userid = new WP_User(wp_create_user( 'My_new_name' , '123458' , 'me@mail.com'));
  $userid->set_role('client');
  // echo whatever you need to return
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_create_user', 'ajax_create_user' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_create_user', 'ajax_create_user' );
```

[Read more about AJAX in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Great answer. But isn't step #1 unnecessary? Why not just set the AJAX URI in the `$.post()` call?

Comment: @rnevius In most cases it is unnecessary and can be safely replaced by `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` - it's just a bulletproof solution in case of specific installations (admin folder being renamed, prefix for the WP installation).

Comment: I agree with you. I was just referring to keeping things all in one place, rather than defining a variable in the head and then making the AJAX call elsewhere. I would rather use `$.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', {action: 'create_user'} , function(data) { ...`, but either works, of course :-)